# Compilation error while using getDeveloperName() of class Schema.RecordTypeInfo

Tags: apex

I have the following block of code and when i execute it from the developer console using anonymous window it is working fine without any error, But it's strange when i copy the same thing in apex class it is giving an compilation error.

```
Map<Id, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeByIdMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosById();
Map<String,String> conversionMap = new Map<String,String>();
for(String r:recordTypeByIdMap.keySet())
{    
    if(!recordTypeByIdMap.get(r).getDeveloperName().startsWithIgnoreCase('Create_'))
    {
        conversionMap.put('Create_'+recordTypeByIdMap.get(r).getDeveloperName(),r);
    }
}
System.debug('-------------'+conversionMap);
```

And here is the error I am getting after copying same code the apex class:

> "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getDeveloperName()
>   from the type Schema.RecordTypeInfo"

Let me know anyone else has faced the same error or someone can give some feasible solution.

Comment: what is an API version of the class ?

Comment: ... i.e. change the API version for the class to 43.0 as this is a recent addition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to have `getDeveloperName()` method available, API version of the class should be 43.0 for now.

Check Summer '18 [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm#rn_apex_new_classes_methods)

> Schema.RecordTypeInfo Class
>
> **New Method**
>
> **getDeveloperName()**
>
> Returns the developer name for this record type.